# Reverting an addition to a string in PostrgreSQL

Tags: string, postgresql, dspace

I followed the steps in this question
[Append text to column data based on the column in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293778/append-text-to-column-data-based-on-the-column-in-postgresql#comment108409993_15293778)
But I made a mistake in the SIMILAR TO clause and the text got added to fields it shouldn't have. How can I reverse it?

Te query I ran was:

```
update metadatavalue set text_value = 'Fil: ' || text_value where metadata_field_id = 136 and text_value not similar to 'Fill:%';
```

How can I remove extre characters from those fields?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim the prepended string off and update the column with the result:

```
UPDATE metadatavalue
SET text_value = regexp_replace(text_value, '^Fil: ','');
```